# Argparse infer variable type from command line format

Tags: python

I have a simple python script that takes input from the command line and subsequently modifies a namelist file. I use it like this:

```
python edit_namelist.py nml section key value
```

The problem is that the value can either be integer, float or string. Currently, I used the following:

```
def infer(s):
    ''' Try to parse input to integer. If it fails, keep it as string '''
    try:
        s = int(s)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return s

parser.add_argument("value",type=infer)
```

This works, but only as long as my input is either integer or string. I wonder whether it is possible to have `argparse` infer the variable type from the format of the command line input, such that

```
python edit_namelist.py nml section key 10
python edit_namelist.py nml section key 10.
python edit_namelist.py nml section key "10"
```

are interpreted as integer, float, and string, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```py
def infer(s):
    try:
        s = float(s)
        if s // 1 == s:
            return int(s)
        return s
    except ValueError:
        return s
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try using `ast.literal_eval(..)`.

```
import ast

def infer(s):
    val = ast.literal_eval(s)
    acceptable_types = (int, str, float)
    if any(isinstance(val, x) for x in acceptable_types):
        return val
    raise SomeException("Bad Input")
```

Comment: This works for integers and floats, but not for strings. However, I noticed that if I pass the input within quotes, it works well for each of them. That means that to input a string, I need double quotes, like this:
`"10"` --> integer, `"10."` --> float, `"'10'"` --> string, `"'ab'"` --> string.